# "Read the sentence aloud" vs "Speak the sentence aloud"

Tags: differences

**A. Read the sentence aloud.**

**B. Speak the sentence aloud.**

Which is more natural among native English speakers?

Is there any subtle difference between the two?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Read the sentence aloud’ requires that the person is literally reading written words as they speak.

‘Speak the sentence aloud’ requires only that the words are spoken and does not denote whether they are read from a page, recalled from memory or any other circumstance which leads to someone speaking out loud.

Both are natural, depending on circumstance. It would not be natural to say someone ‘read the sentence aloud’ if they were not actually reading.

Comment: But equally, one would be unlikely to use "speak" when they are actually being asked to *read* the sentence from something written.

Comment: @TrevorD That is true, also 'Say the sentence out loud' might be the more natural form if asking someone to recite from memory.